# How to visualize ner dataset tagged using BILOU?

Tags: nlp, lstm, visualization, learning

I have a dataset for ner which is tagged using BILOU tagging method and example of same is below

```
Minjun  B-Person
is  O
from    O
South   B-Location
Korea   I-Location
.   O
```

i wish to visualize how model learn if i use lstm with crfD
for example how this model is learning context of current sentence